# @change not firing on programmatically changed values

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have the below textarea with a change event.

```
<textarea @change="inputChanged" ref="input">
```

When I manually enter data 'inputChanged' is called. 
However when I used a button that that is at the top of the page to update the value programatically.

```
this.$refs.input.value = "Hello";
```

The textarea updates with the value 'Hello' however 'inputChanged'. Is not called.

Why is this? And how can I get the change event to first on programatic textarea change? Ideally I don't want to have to use JQuery.

Comment: You could use model: `<input v-model="message" placeholder="edit me">`

Comment: What are you doing in your `inputChanged` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind the text area using `v-model` and then use a computed property to get/set the value.  Check out the documentation [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter)

#HTML

```
<textarea v-model="text">
```

#Typescript

```
computed:{
  text:{
    get(){
      return this.$refs.input.value;
    },
    set(value){
      if(this.$refs.input.value != value){
        this.$refs.input.value = value;
        // Do other stuff here
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if I am not mistaken you can not nest `get`/`set` properties directly inside your computed object. You should have another object like this https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter no?

Comment: @samayo You are absolutely correct, I was going to fast when I answered the question.  Answer updated.