# Accessing Vue properties inside of the data function

Tags: vuejs2

I using Vue on a personal project to learn more about Vue and JS.  It's going to be a markdown editor that backs up to the web.  I'm using Vue 2 / Webpack.  For the markdown editor I'm using [SimpleMDE](https://github.com/sparksuite/simplemde-markdown-editor).

I scaffolded the project based on [this post](https://itnext.io/vuejs-and-webpack-4-from-scratch-part-1-94c9c28a534a).  The project is a root Vue instance with a single custom component.
The custom component holds the editor.  The template looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <textarea
      id="noteEditor"
      v-model="note"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

SimpleMDE looks for the textarea instance and converts it to the markdown editor like this:

```
editor = new SimpleMDE({
    element: document.getElementById('noteEditor'),
    contents: note,
    forceSync: true
  })
```

And by convert, I mean the SimpleMDE code hides the textarea and adds in a bunch of other HTML.  So the text area is still in the DOM, just hidden from view.  `forceSync: true` above tells the editor to update the contents of the now hidden textarea with the contents of the markdown editor.

So far so good, but since this happens programmatically (instead of someone typing directly into the text editor) vue won't update its internal model to reflect what's in the markdown editor.

I've tried a bunch of different things like [computed values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47203250/change-not-firing-on-programmatically-changed-values) and watchers, but nothing seems to work.  I figured the simplest thing for me to try was to use setInterval and poll for changes.  There are no errors.  And the setInverval function is getting called, but `note` isn't getting updated (according to Vue dev tools on chrome). But it's still not working.  And I have no idea why.

I think there's something going on where the scope of the note inside the data function isn't accessible (shouldn't closure mean it is?).  Is there some other way to access `note`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  TIA!

Edit: Here's the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/2owwy882kn) (but vue dev tools don't work, did I do something wrong?)

Here's my components code:

```
 <template>
  <div>
    <textarea
      id="noteEditor"
      v-model="note"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import SimpleMDE from 'simplemde'

var editor
var note = 'i will need to be fixed, when loading from a real source'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      note: note
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    if (!editor) {
      /* eslint-disable-next-line no-debugger */
      // debugger
      editor = new SimpleMDE({
        element: document.getElementById('noteEditor'),
        contents: note,
        forceSync: true
      })
    }
    setInterval(function () {
      if (note !== editor.value()) {
        note = editor.value()
      }
    }, 1000)    
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="stylus" scpoed>
@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css'
@import 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/simplemde/latest/simplemde.min.css'
</style>
```

Comment: could you share your code in https://codesandbox.io?

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking!  I'm about to sleep now, but I'll get something up tomorrow.

Comment: ok good night my bro

Comment: Hi, edited to add the codesandbox

Comment: If the library doesn't generate the appropriate events when it makes programmatic changes, Vue won't detect them, which appears to be what you've discovered. However, looking at the documentation, it seems the library does [trigger it's own events](https://github.com/sparksuite/simplemde-markdown-editor#event-handling). Rather than using `forceSync`, you could listen for those events in your component and update the note appropriately.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, that's a much cleaner way to do what I want. Thanks!

Comment: I've been doing some more research and it seems note isn't reactive.  when I set `note = editor.value()`, the proxy function (which I have a breakpoint on) never gets called.  Any ideas on what could cause this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totally sure why this works, but I think I was accessing the wrong "note".  So I removed the local note variable and hardcoded an initial value in the data function:

```
data: function () {
  return {
    note: 'test'
  }
}
```

and then used `this.note` instead of just `note` everywhere `note` occurred.  And finally to get the correct `this`, I used bind for the change handler

```
editor.codemirror.on('change', this.changeNote.bind(this))
```

Below is the full code.  Thanks everyone for reading!

```
 <template>
  <div>
    <textarea
      id="noteEditor"
      v-model="note"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import SimpleMDE from 'simplemde'

var editor

export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      note: 'test'
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    if (!editor) {
      /* eslint-disable-next-line no-debugger */
      // debugger
      editor = new SimpleMDE({
        element: document.getElementById('noteEditor'),
        contents: this.note
      })
    }
    editor.codemirror.on('change', this.changeNote.bind(this))
  },
  methods: {
    changeNote () {
      this.note = editor.value()
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="stylus" scpoed>
@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css'
@import 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/simplemde/latest/simplemde.min.css'
</style>
```